# np.load from relative file in the python package

Tags: python, np, pyproject.toml, flit

I have created a python package and I need to have `np.load('./my_file.npy')` in my package.
when I install package and run the code the path is not correct and python cannot find the file

I tried the following code as well

```py
dirname = Path(__file__).parent
path = dirname / 'my_file.npy'
np.load(str(path))
```

In `pyproject.toml` file I have as well

```ini
[tool.flit.sdist]
include = [
    "my_file.npy",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand you correctly that you want to include the file my_file.npy in your package using flit?

Flit‘s docs about data files:
https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/pyproject_toml.html?highlight=Data#external-data-section

I have nothing special in my toml file and it includes my data files in the package.